# FtpInboundFileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true) not deleting remote files after transfer

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying with spring boot, integration ftp example (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html, 15.5.1 ). I'm able to read files from remote directory, some how it's not deleting the files with flag setDeleteRemoteFiles(true). Please let me know if I'm missing to set any flags to remove remote files.

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    sf.setHost("localhost");
    sf.setPort(21);
    sf.setUsername("sudaredd");
    sf.setPassword("");
    return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
}

 @Bean
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(ftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("");
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }
  @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
    public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
                new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(ftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("ftp-inbound"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return source;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All the config looks good.

Try to switch on `DEBUG` for the `org.springframework.integration` category to track behavior.

OTOH, please, be sure that your FTP server support delete operation and your user really has a permission to perform that operation.

Since `@InboundChannelAdapter` performs its task via `taskScheduler` you might just miss an error in the logs.

Would be also great if you are able to debug the code and place break point in the `AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.copyFileToLocalDirectory()` to follow with the logic and determine what may be wrong.

Comment: If we've same file name in local vs remote, it's pulling file from local directory and handling over to service activator. if I remove files from my local directory, then it's copying to local and removing remote files.

Comment: Ok! So , what is the question? This is expected behavior. If you would like to remove remote file any way, consider to use 'RemoteFileTemplate` directly after your service.